# How to use IsTabStop for an Image control?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a form with some 'textboxes' and an 'Image' control. The textboxes have the 'IsTabStop' property, so when set to true and I press "tab" on keyboard, it gains focus.

I want the same behavior for an 'Image' control, but it doesn't have the 'IsTabStop' property.
Is there any simple way to a 'Image' control behave like a textbox in this case?.

I want the 'Image' to have the focus, because if It has the 'MouseLeftButtonDown' event, so the person can press space bar on keyboard when it has the focus.

Comment: This may help: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/13b1896a-b0e0-44ac-94c6-3aaa3ae9a63c

Answer (score 4):

I don't know the purposes of your requirement, but may be you can solve this problem using a `Button` with a Custom Template that shows the image.

```
<Button Width="Auto" Height="Auto">
    <Button.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image Stretch="Uniform" Source="YourPathHere.png" Width="64" Height="64" />
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Button.Template>
</Button>
```

Now, the button has the `IsTabStop`Property and is showing your image. Hope this helps

Comment: It didn't really worked. But it helped in my solution which I will post. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I already had a custom button class which inheritance from 'Button'. My control manages the Button 'Content' and adds an Image. I think that was the key to solve it (manage the content of the button).

I just replaced to my control and changed a few personal details and it worked.